# How can I make a method that accepts an async closure argument?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, closures

I'm trying to make a little newtype wrapper for `Arc<tokio::sync::RwLock<T>>`.  I have a `with()` method that takes a non-async closure, and this works fine.

Now I want to add a `with_async()` method that accepts an async closure.  But the compiler gives an error.

Is this possible somehow?

```rust
use std::sync::Arc;
use tokio::sync::RwLock;
use std::future::Future;

#[derive(Debug, Default)]
pub struct AtomicRw<T>(Arc<RwLock<T>>);
impl<T> From<T> for AtomicRw<T> {
    fn from(t: T) -> Self {
        Self(Arc::new(RwLock::new(t)))
    }
}


impl<T> AtomicRw<T> {

    // This compiles.
    pub async fn with<R, F>(&self, f: F) -> R
    where
        F: FnOnce(&T) -> R,
    {
        let lock = self.0.read().await;
        f(&lock)
    }
    
    pub async fn with_async<R, F>(&self, f: F) -> R
    where
        // Error: error[E0562]: `impl Trait` only allowed in function and inherent method argument and return types, not in `Fn` trait return types
        F: FnOnce(&T) -> impl Future<Output = R>,
    {
        let lock = self.0.read().await;
        f(&lock).await
    }
    
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    struct Car {
        year: u16,
    }

    let atomic_car = AtomicRw::from(Car{year: 2016});
    
    atomic_car.with(|c| println!("year: {}", c.year)).await;
    let _year = atomic_car.with(|c| c.year).await;
    
    atomic_car.with_async(|c| async {
        println!("year: {}", c.year)
        
    }).await;
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=15c47459d7cdd2919770917c3c11a106)

The full error is:

```
error[E0562]: `impl Trait` only allowed in function and inherent method return types, not in `Fn` trait return types
  --> src/main.rs:29:26
   |
29 |         F: FnOnce(&T) -> impl Future<Output = R>,
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

edit: I was able to get it to compile by changing the fn to this:

```rust
    pub async fn with_async<'a, R, F>(&'a self, f: impl FnOnce(&T) -> F ) -> R
    where
        F: Future<Output = R>,
    {
        let lock = self.0.read().await;
        f(&lock).await
    }
```

However, when I try to use it, I still get a compile error about lifetimes:

```
    atomic_car.with_async(|c| async {
        println!("year: {}", c.year)
```

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:47:31
   |
47 |       atomic_car.with_async(|c| async move {
   |  ____________________________--_^
   | |                            ||
   | |                            |return type of closure `{async block@src/lib.rs:47:31: 50:6}` contains a lifetime `'2`
   | |                            has type `&'1 Car`
48 | |         println!("year: {}", c.year)
49 | |         
50 | |     }).await;
   | |_____^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
```

Comment: Try with a third type parameter `Fut: Future<Output = R>` on the function.

Comment: thx, yeah the `with_async()` method compiles.   But I get a lifetime error when actually trying to invoke it.   [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c2365ba1dd8f3ac57616b9ff8a9fe492)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution [here](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/function-that-takes-an-async-closure/61663/2) with detailed explanation.

Unfortunately it appears to require dynamic dispatch and for the caller to add `.boxed()` and include the `FutureExt` trait, all of which is ugly.

If anyone has a better solution without these downsides, please post.

This works.

```rust
use std::sync::Arc;
use tokio::sync::RwLock;
use futures::future::{BoxFuture, FutureExt};

#[derive(Debug, Default)]
pub struct AtomicRw<T>(Arc<RwLock<T>>);
impl<T> From<T> for AtomicRw<T> {
    #[inline]
    fn from(t: T) -> Self {
        Self(Arc::new(RwLock::new(t)))
    }
}


impl<T> AtomicRw<T> {
    
    pub async fn with_async<R>(&self, f: impl Fn(&'_ T) -> BoxFuture<'_, R>) -> R {
        let lock = self.0.read().await;
        f(&lock).await
    }
    
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    struct Car {
        year: u16,
    }

    let atomic_car = AtomicRw::from(Car{year: 2016});
        
    atomic_car.with_async(|c| async {
        println!("year: {}", c.year)
    }.boxed()).await;
    
    let year2 = atomic_car.with_async(|c| async {c.year}.boxed()).await;
    assert_eq!(year2, 2016);
    
    let atomic_num = AtomicRw::from(2016u64);
    let year3 = atomic_num.with_async(|n| async {n.clone()}.boxed()).await;
    assert_eq!(year3, 2016);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=dfe8917e604c4a907c4a1a51af118ff4)